# Run cron job on local server

Tags: cron, server-setup

I'm trying to run a cron job on local server for a Magento site, using some of the following commands in terminal:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website.local/cron.sh
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website.local/cron.sh
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website.local/cron.php
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/website.local/cron.php
```

I am returned with the following:

> -bash: */5: No such file or directory

Can someone please advise how to run a cron job on local server for a Magento site?

Comment: For a one off run you can just access cron.php in your browser.

Comment: These are not command line items. They belong in a crontab file.

Answer (score 3):

The lines you have posted are not direct Bash commands, but Crontab rules. They should not be entered in terminal.

Try entering

```
crontab -e
```

in console, and only then pasting this commands to the editor, and saving (Ctrl+x). 
Or, as frshjb373 commented - you can open cron.php from your webshop's root in web browser.